# MySql errors while executing queries on a Django project on AWS Lambda function

Tags: mysql, django, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, pymysql

1. I have a ***Django*** project hosted on ***AWS Lambda function***.
2. This microservice uses ***pymysql*** to connect to ***AWS Aurora RDS database***.
3. This service executes one and only one query over and over again.
4. 1 in 200 times the query fails with *EOF packet* error.

In order to investigate this issue i have implemented a "repeater" which would repeat the same query if one fails (maximum 2 repeats with 0.25 seconds delay).

Once again, in a rare ocasion, a query has failed and I expected to see a successful query after the first reattempt. However it failed in all 3 consecutive calls with all *DIFFERENT* error messages.

Error messages (in order):

1. AssertionError: Protocol error, expecting EOF
2. django.db.utils.InternalError: Packet sequence number wrong - got 24 expected 1
3. django.db.utils.InterfaceError: (0, '')

These are errors from 3 separate queries executed against ***MySql Aurora RDS database***. (I just wanted to ephesize that indeed it is not a stack trace but rather different query errors).

More useful info:

1. The microservice uses ***Django ORM*** to create queries.
2. The database is in Master-Slave configuration and those queries go against a Slave database.
3. The parameters observed in Master and Slave databases (such as CPU usage, free RAM space, various latencies, various throughputs, etc.) are completely normal and do not indicate any potential errors.
4. It is not a multithreaded environment.

***Error stack traces:***

```
Complete stack for *EOF error*:
https://pastebin.com/BracLTZX

Complete stack for *Packet sequence error*:
https://pastebin.com/fYmRGh69

Complete stack for *Interface error*:
https://pastebin.com/bstG1r2q
```

Comment: Would you consider posting your error log complete content, last 400 lines?

Comment: I have edited my original post and added stack traces.

Comment: Would you consider posting your MySQL error log complete content, last 400 lines from the AWS RDS microservice ?   Someone else may be able to interpret your posted stack traces.